# abind Error when converting a .tif raster data object to an sf object using st_as_sf() in R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, sf, stars

When I try to convert a `.tif` raster data object to an `sf` object using `st_as_sf()` in `R`, I get the following error:

```
Error in abind(x, along = length(dim(x)) + 1) : along must be between 0 and 2
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

The `.tif` data for which to reproduce this I got from https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-data-quality-indicators-rev11/data-download.

The error occurs both for the Data Context and Mean Administrative Unit Area data. Choose `GeoTiff` and `30 sec (1 km) resolution`.

The reprex `R` code is then (for the Data Context data, for example):

```
library(stars)

# Load data
gpw_raw <- read_stars("gpw_v4_data_quality_indicators_rev11_context_30_sec.tif")

# Attemt to convert .tif into sf object
gpw <- st_as_sf(gpw_raw)
```

One resource I used, which in the end did not allow me to solve the issue, is: https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars5.html#vectorizing-a-raster-object-to-an-sf-object

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st_as_sf` fails if the stars object is a "proxy" object. I've downloaded the smaller 30 minute dataset to demonstrate.

Read in as a proxy object and it fails:

```
> gpw_raw <- read_stars("gpw_v4_data_quality_indicators_rev11_context_30_min.tif", proxy=TRUE)
> gpw <- st_as_sf(gpw_raw)
Error in abind(x, along = length(dim(x)) + 1) : 
  along must be between 0 and 2
```

Read in not as a proxy object and it works:

```
> gpw_raw <- read_stars("gpw_v4_data_quality_indicators_rev11_context_30_min.tif", proxy=FALSE)
> gpw <- st_as_sf(gpw_raw)
>
```

This is because somewhere in `st_as_sf` it is expecting to find the data, but instead a proxy object only has a pointer to the data, reading it on demand, but it seems `st_as_sf` isn't demanding enough. Possibly a bug in the `st_as_sf` function, report to the `stars` package: https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/ issue tracker if you want.

I tried this with the 30 second data but that is 43200 x 21600 cells which means nearly a billion polygons when converted using `st_as_sf`. If you've got the RAM for that then fine, read it in with `proxy=FALSE` and it should work. Otherwise, find another way to deal with this data.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, thanks a lot for your quick help! This solves my issue and also explains why it took an incredible amount of time to load. Have a good day!